# Troll slandering the company

Tags: social-media

I am very active on some popular (my country-specific) Facebook web developer communities; some months ago, a guy
began there posting problematic comments. After a while, he began targeting my company (where I work as employee); his arguments were that their hiring process was a scam, but the worst were the overly obscene and sexist insults he kept writing about our HR girls.

I'm never concerned usually about the casual troll, but this guy was explicitly targeting the company I work in, and I just cannot tolerate obscenities casually thrown to women, so I contacted the FB group admin and made him ban the guy.

He came back just yesterday with the same behaviour, save the sexist obscenities: after he bragged on how he "sent fake CVs to scam companies", he reprised the rants about our hiring process.
I know how my company hires and the level of our engineers is outstanding (also on a personal side): I think the guy either is awfully bad, or erratic and just can't realize how he has been kicked at the first stage; or, maybe, he is making up accusations just to troll and annoy me. So I made him banned again (I hope permanently).

Should the story repeat itself, do you think it's time to report the thing to my HR department? I thought maybe without overtly pointing out the guy, but just asking "how do I deal with someone continuosly slandering the company in a public forum?"

Comment: why not point him out?

Comment: @Kilisi Fair question, but if I was sure about the course of action I wouldn't have posted here :) Maybe I'm giving just too much importance to a troll.

Comment: Could you clarify your role in your current company? There's a big difference between how you should respond if you're the CEO/owner and if you're an entry level employee in a multinational.

Comment: @PhilipKendall fair question too. I am a senior employee. Will add to the question.

Comment: Really? Who cares what some troll does? And this as an _ordinary_ employee. The more attention he gets the more it will escalate and the more people will know about your _crappy_ hiring process. Just let it be. If this botters you than you should have become a sheriff :-)

Comment: @red-shield Yes, _really_. I post here _exactly_ to assess and confront my thoughts about the proper course of action. Still I am am publiclty targeted with mentions to my work and my workplace (let alone the profanities which are right away defamatory), so the question is at least legitimate.

Comment: Welcome new user, I think it's a great question.  I'm not really sure what the best course of action is.

Comment: @red-shield - that's not really an .. effective solution to "what should our OP do now".  it's a tough one.

Comment: "Certainly you should not personally engage them online" that's exactly right.  IMO our op shouldn't have gotten involved in having them banned etc - it just "involves our OP" in the event.

Comment: Would be good if those who voted the question down could explain their reasons. It's a legitimate problem. What's not clear to what extent there is a relationship between you/your company and that guy. You have started your question with stating that you are active on some kind of discussion board; what were the problematic comments posted there? Were those comments addressed to you personally? Is it possible that this person is targeting the company due to prior acrimonious interaction over the discussion board? How you being active on some online discussion space is relevant to the problem?

Comment: @Konrad Fair question: and yes, it could be possible. This guy was already noticeable for constant passive-aggressive whining and most of all vastly incompetent answers. I don't remember but likely I did a remark, and he took "revenge" on me. I can be caustic, but I never offend or take things to personal/childish level.
 
As I said, normally I let trolls slip; the novelty here was his addressing my work and my workplace directly, and I was disturbed by the filthy and sexist comments about the colleagues, that were repeatedly written in public.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you're engaging this person, which is absolutely the only motive a troll has.  You've also managed to draw attention to your company.

There's an ancient saying that dates all the way back to floppy disks.

**PLEASE DON'T FEED THE TROLL**

You're feeding him.

Stop it.

Comment: [Why should trolls not be fed?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/why-should-trolls-not-be-fed)

Comment: IMHO very little food, as long as I help the group's administrators to kick him out, thus making the world a cleaner place.

Comment: @Czar trolls collect kickoust like badges of honor, then make new names, and come back.  Take it from a grandmaster troll.  The only winning move, is not to play.  Back in the ancient days of the usenet, if there was a troll, first warnings of PDFTT would go out, then if the troll continued, a Passive Ignore Simultaneous Strike would be called.  Yes, it has a pity acronym.  The entire board would ignore the troll, he'd get tired and go away, or he'd learn to behave.  We had much thicker skins back then.

Comment: @RichardU Fair enough, but I'm almost certain that the guy uses real identity and profile.

Comment: @Czar so what if he does?  You're still feeding him.  He's getting laughs out of it, and you're getting upset to the point you want to contact HR.  Who's winning this battle?

Comment: @RichardU Nope. I'm confident he's more disturbed than real troll. Actually, I think he got scared. As for the kickouts, it's more "public service", if I were hear doing racist or violent remarks you would to the same to me :)

Comment: @Czar honestly, I'd ignore you.  But, I'm from a different generation, I suspect.  Growing up, I got called every name in the book, thanks to all of my disabilities. I learned to ignore most of it, and zing those I couldn't.  99% it's ignore.

Comment: @RichardU It's not that I do not value your suggestions (in the end, I accepted your answer). Still the direct defamation seemed to me a legit concern.

Comment: @Czar Thank you, and I don't mean to come across as hostile, just pragmatic.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer simply doesn't at all address the question.  (Sure, everyone agrees that on the forum in question, the OP should obviously just ignore the perp.)  The question is, should the OP alert the company to the issue, in what way, etc.

Comment: "Should the story repeat itself, do you think it's time to report the thing to my HR department?"

Answer (score 4):

By interacting with him you validate him and his claims.

Do not interact with him. If you can, ban him. If you can't ban him, report him. If you can't report him, ignore him. Don't do anything other than ban, report, or ignore.

> report the thing to my HR department

While you would report the anonymous troll, you'd also report your response. Given your emotional investment, it's possible that said response wasn't always in line with what the company and specifically HR expects the company's representatives to do. If so, reporting will get you in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

A difficult issue, I would say ...

- Sure, your owners/managers need to at least be aware of this

So:  in a low-key way, tell them. And probably leave it alone after that.  It's not "your problem to solve", it's a management problem.

I'd use language like this, to managers/HR ..

> "Say guys - have you been on this facebook/whatever page? URL.  Notice there's some dickwad who keeps slamming our company - he is totally vulgar too.  This drives me crazy.  I'm pretty sure it's this person XYZ.  I thought the best and only thing I can really do is alert you guys to it.  It's a job for management. Very annoying situation!  Sorry to bring bad news!"

BTW. I would say you **possibly were wrong-footed** when you initially had the PIQ blocked on the site.  Again it's not your job: that would be a job for your management.

You don't even want to be "seen to be involved" in any way you know?

(In fact, if it ever comes up that you did have-him-blocked once, I would downplay it totally:  "Yeah, when I first saw that profanity I messaged the site moderators who seemed to block him for awhile. It seemed to contnue so I've just alerted you guys ... PR disasters are above my payscale!" ... that sort of thing?)

Hope it helps.  Delicate one!

Comment: Seen this way, it seems just too much hassle for a disturbed guy. :)

Comment: I want to add that the fact that I had him kicked the first time out had nothing to do with me, but directly with the sexist issues. I think that, in general, no professional group should have people complaining with women using dirty sexual profanities. 

I brough up the problem because the second time he seemed particularly concerned with my company.